# How can I get the total?

Tags: sql, oracle, count, sum, oracle-sqldeveloper

I could not get the exact query to get the over all total of the total table. i want to get the total of each date in call_time table. here's my query:

```
SELECT call_type, channel, call_time,
       count (CASE WHEN upper(status) = upper('no answer') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS cnt_no_answer,
       count (CASE WHEN upper(status) = upper('answered') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS cnt_answer,
       count (status) AS cnt_total
FROM   app_account.cc_call
WHERE  channel = 'DAHDI/i1/'
AND    call_time BETWEEN ('30-DEC-2013') AND ('04-JAN-2014')
GROUP BY call_type, channel, call_time;
```

Some output of that query:

```
CALL_TYPE        CHANNEL    CALL_TIME CNT_NO_ANSWER  CNT_ANSWERED   CNT_TOTAL
LANDLINE         DAHDI/i1/  03-JAN-14     1            0               1
MOBILE-SUN       DAHDI/i1/  03-JAN-14     0            1               1
MOBILE-SUN       DAHDI/i1/  03-JAN-14     1            0               1
LANDLINE         DAHDI/i1/  03-JAN-14     1            0               1
LANDLINE         DAHDI/i1/  03-JAN-14     1            0               1
LANDLINE         DAHDI/i1/  03-JAN-14     1            0               1
MOBILE-SUN       DAHDI/i1/  02-JAN-14     1            0               1
MOBILE-SUN       DAHDI/i1/  02-JAN-14     0            1               1
LANDLINE         DAHDI/i1/  02-JAN-14     0            1               1
LANDLINE         DAHDI/i1/  02-JAN-14     1            0               1
MOBILE-SMART     DAHDI/i1/  02-JAN-14     1            0               1
```

My excepted Output:

```
CALL_TIME  CNT_NO_ANSWER CNT_ANSWERED
03-JAN-14   27             10   
02-JAN-14   48             20
```

Please help me.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and expected output?

Comment: What doesn't work in your query?

Comment: @Rachcha I ALREADY PUT THE OUTPUT

Comment: @Szymon actually none, but i want to get the query that would get the total of each date and distinct it if have same data in channel table

Comment: Does your call_time contain the time part as well or just date?

Comment: @Szymon yes call_time contains date and time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CALL_TYPE, CHANNEL, TRUNC(CALL_TIME)
      ,COUNT (CASE WHEN UPPER(STATUS) = UPPER('no answer') THEN 1 END) AS CNT_NO_ANSWER
      ,COUNT (CASE WHEN UPPER(STATUS) = UPPER('answered') THEN 1 END) AS CNT_ANSWER
      ,COUNT (STATUS) AS CNT_TOTAL
FROM APP_ACCOUNT.CC_CALL
WHERE CHANNEL = 'DAHDI/i1/'
AND CALL_TIME BETWEEN ('30-DEC-2013') AND ('04-JAN-2014')
GROUP BY CALL_TYPE, CHANNEL, TRUNC(CALL_TIME);
```

If `CALL_TIME` contains time value and you want to `GROUP BY` each date, you should `trunc` the `CALL_TIME` to its date.

Answer (score 4):

Use something like the following:

```
  SELECT CALL_TYPE, CHANNEL, TRUNC(CALL_TIME)
         , COUNT (CASE UPPER(STATUS)
                     WHEN UPPER('no answer') THEN 1
                     ELSE NULL
                  END) AS CNT_NO_ANSWER
         , COUNT (CASE UPPER(STATUS)
                       WHEN UPPER('answered') THEN 1
                       ELSE NULL
                  END) AS CNT_ANSWER
         , COUNT (STATUS) AS CNT_TOTAL
    FROM APP_ACCOUNT.CC_CALL
   WHERE CHANNEL = 'DAHDI/i1/'
     AND CALL_TIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('30-DEC-2013')
                       AND TO_DATE('04-JAN-2014')
GROUP BY CALL_TYPE, CHANNEL, TRUNC(CALL_TIME);
```

The major change I have made is `TRUNC(CALL_TIME)`. Oracle stores dates as datetime values, which have dates as well as time values. Hence, when you use `GROUP BY ..., CALL_TIME, ...`, what really happens is that the grouping is done for the datetime values, not date values. Only the calls which were made on the exact time accurate to a fraction of a second will be grouped together, which is not the expected behavior. Hence use `GROUP BY TRUNC(CALL_DATE)` when you have to show the grouping by day.

**EDIT:**

To get the overall total for each day, you have already used `COUNT(STATUS) AS CNT_TOTAL` in your query! It would give you the total number of calls if the column is a not null and status is recorded for each call. If this column contains null values, I would suggest you use `COUNT(*) AS CNT_TOTAL` as it would count all the rows without regards to constraints on columns.

As far as the "for each day" part, `TRUNC(datetime)` function can truncate datetime values from their year down to their minute. This means, if you want to get the number of calls, or any other statistics, each year then you can simply use `TRUNC(call_time, 'YYYY')`. On the other hand, if you want call statistics for each hour, you can use `TRUNC(call_time, 'HH')` or `TRUNC(call_time, 'HH24')`. Same goes for a minute.

But beware, unless you use a `TO_CHAR` function to display dates, the front-end dev tools like Toad or SQL Developer display datetime values in the DD-MON-YYYY format, discarding the time information. This is what got you in the first place. Hence, if you group by truncating datetimes to an hour or a minute, and even though the results are correct, you will see repeated date in DD-MON-YYYY format. Hence, don't get confused.

For further reading on `TRUNC`, I would suggest [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions209.htm#SQLRF06151) AND [this link to techonthenet.com](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php). For `TO_CHAR`, [Oracle Docs here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) has detailed and easy to understand explanation.

Comment: Thanks buddy for the query, its running properly :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you find a question or answer which people find helpful and well written, people upvote it. If you find an answer to your question satisfying your requirements, you accept it. It is indeed a very pleasing comment of yours here but on SO, thanks are generally expressed using upvotes and acceptance marks.

Comment: Hey buddy, I have another question. I want to get the over all total each day?

Comment: Yes but what i mean is i need to get the overall total of no answer and answered each day

Comment: Just one thing to ask- is there any other value in `status` column than `'answered'` and `'no answer'`?

Comment: Well, then the column selected as `CNT_TOTAL` alias is itself all that you need! You're already selecting the overall total in your query! Please read the EDIT section of my answer carefully as that is what I've been trying to tell you in this comment.

Answer (score 3):

To get the day-wise count you need to group with `CALL_TIME`. Try like this,

```
SELECT call_type, 
       channel, 
       trunc(call_time),
       count (CASE WHEN upper(status) = upper('no answer') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS cnt_no_answer,
       count (CASE WHEN upper(status) = upper('answered') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS cnt_answer
FROM   happ_account.cc_call
WHERE  channel = 'DAHDI/i1/'
AND    call_time BETWEEN to_date('30-DEC-2013', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND to_date('04-JAN-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
GROUP BY call_type, channel, trunc(call_time);
```